# Python- Get list of Duplicates and seperate list without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm trying to create two new dfs based on my original df (I have df1 and want to create df2 & df3). df1 = Original, df2= duplicates, df3= removed duplicates. Here's the thing, I want all instances of duplciates in df2 and df3 to removed even the original duplicate value. I'm only looking at duplicates in the 'Color' column. Below are the results I want

df1

| Store | Clothing | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Target | Shirt | Blue |
| Walmart | Shirt | Green |
| JC Penny | Shirt | Orange |
| Target | Shirt | Yellow |
| Target | Pants | Blue |
| Walmart | Socks | Purple |
| JC Penny | Pants | Green |
| Walmart | Socks | Orange |

df2

| Store | Clothing | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Target | Shirt | Blue |
| Walmart | Shirt | Green |
| JC Penny | Shirt | Orange |
| Target | Pants | Blue |
| JC Penny | Pants | Green |
| Walmart | Socks | Orange |

df3

| Store | Clothing | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Target | Shirt | Yellow |
| Walmart | Socks | Purple |

To create df2 & df3 I've tried the code below, but it does not keep all the duplicates. For example, if df1 has 4 'Blue' values, it only puts 3. What I want is df2 to have all 4 'Blue' values and df3 to only have non duplicate values (no blue values).

```
df2 = df1[df1[['Color']].duplicated() == True]
print(df2)
```

and

```
df3 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='Color', keep='none')
print(df3)
```

Obviously the second code block retuns an error

Comment: "Obviously the second code block retuns an error" That isn't really "obvious", but in any case, if you are getting an error, post the *full error message including the stack trace*... and note, the error actually tells you **exactly what the problem is**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have df1 and I want to create what I've shown as df2 & df3.

I get an error with 'none' becuase none is not defined in that code, it must be 'first' or  'last'. So I'm curious if there is another way to  do this?
'''
df3 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='Color', keep='none')
'''

Answer (score 1):

For df2:

Instead of using `.duplicated() == True` - use the built in parameters within the duplicated method, see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

eg.

```
df2 = df1[df1[['Color']].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

For df3:

You can not use `'none'` for the parameter `keep`. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)
and use `keep=False` instead to obtain the wanted `df3`.

eg.

```
df3 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='Color', keep=False)
```

Hope it helps!